# Solr Dynamic fields with Attributes

Tags: solr

In our Document Management application (J2EE webapp) user can folders/subfolder and upload documents in it. ACL is very complex (Default Permission/Role level/User level) in our system. 
User can access folder via Role a direct OR via User level assignment.

We are using solr 4.3 for search funcationlity. We want to store ACL related information in dynamic field (as its very complex) and run use it in Solr query for ACL check.

((DefaultAccess = Yes or allowed users has u1 or (R1 or r2) in allowed roles) and u1 not in blocked users and ((R1 and R2) not in blocked roles or allowed user has u1) on Folder 0) and 
((DefaultAccess = Yes or allowed users has u1 or (R1 or r2) in allowed roles) and u1 not in blocked users and ((R1 and R2) not in blocked roles or allowed user has u1) on Folder 1) and 
((DefaultAccess = Yes or allowed users has u1 or (R1 or r2) in allowed roles) and u1 not in blocked users and ((R1 and R2) not in blocked roles or allowed user has u1) on Folder 2) and 
((DefaultAccess = Yes or allowed users has u1 or (R1 or r2) in allowed roles) and u1 not in blocked users and ((R1 and R2) not in blocked roles or allowed user has u1) on Folder 3)

Is it possible to have dynamic field with multiple attributes(DefaultAccess,AllowedRoles,AllowedUsers,BlockedUsers,BlockedRoles) where we can run above query?

Please let me know any further information required.